# pyspark doesn't support delimiter greater than 127

Tags: pyspark

I am using pyspark on AWS EMR where I am using Spark 2.4.3 to read CSV file with a separator passed as a command line argument.

The code is as follows.

```
loadDF = spark.read.csv("s3://TEST/sample.csv", header='false', inferSchema='false', sep=chr(self.delimiter))
```

If self.delimiter is set to any value less than 127 then no problem in reading CSV file. But I want it to work for a delimiter value 198, 199 or 200.

Is this a limit in pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The limitation is in Spark 2.4.2. The latest Spark 3.0.1 which comes with the latest AWS EMR supports any delimiter.